# Simultaneously monitoring multiple log files (over ssh) on Windows?

Tags: windows, logging, terminal, monitoring

I've used poderosa(a .NET terminal app) to monitor logs on multiple linux/solaris servers. This application is NOT getting currently maintained and I've had several problems with it.

I'm wondering what other users do to simultaneously monitor several logs in real-time(as in tail -f logfile). I would like to be able to tab/cascade several ssh tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Putty Connection Manager](http://puttycm.free.fr/) to add tabs to PuTTy.  Then SSH into the machine twice and tab back and forth.

[Tutorial on Setting it Up](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/get-tabs-for-your-putty/)

Answer (score 7):

You could just ssh to one server, and use [mutitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) from there to tail the logs on all the other servers.

Comment: sounds like it is useful except I am not supposed to install any software on the linux/solaris servers.

Comment: multitail will work over ssh.  multitail -l 'ssh host tail -f file1' -l 'ssh host tail -f file2

Answer (score 2):

Ssh to one of the server, run screen on it.  You can then split the screen into multiple windows, and each one of them do

```
ssh serverX tail -f /path/to/log/file
```

An incidental advantage to this method is that you don't have to restart the tails each time you connect - instead, you can just reattach to the running screen session.

Comment: thank you.
sounds like it is useful except I am not supposed to install any software on the linux/solaris servers. I need a solution from my windows XP box.

Answer (score 2):

From bash you can (save in `~/.bashrc` or something):

```
function create-follower () {
    local _NAME=$1;
    local _USER=$2;
    local _HOST=$3;
    local _PATH=$4;

    if ! [ "${_NAME}" ]\
    || ! [ "${_USER}" ]\
    || ! [ "${_HOST}" ]\
    || ! [ "${_PATH}" ] ; then
        {   echo "Cannot create log follower." ;
            echo;
            echo "Usage: create-follower NAME USER HOST LOG-FILE";
        } >&2;
        return 1 ;
    fi ;

    eval "function ${_NAME}(){ ssh ${_USER}@${_HOST} tail -f \"${_PATH}\" & }"
}

function activate-followers () {
    if (( $# < 1 )) ; then
        {   echo "You must specify at least one follower to use" ;
            echo ;
            echo "Usage:" ;
            echo "    activate-followers follower1 [follower2 ... followerN]";
        } >&2;
        return 1 ;
    fi ;

    for FOLLOW in "${@}" ; do
        ${FOLLOW} ;
    done ;

    wait;
}

function stop-followers () {
    if [ "$(jobs)" ] ; then
        kill -9 $(jobs | perl -pe 's/\[([0-9]+)\].*/%$1/') ;
    fi ;
}
```

And then from your shell, define the logs you want to follow:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ create-follower test1 user1 localhost /tmp/log-1.txt
[dsm@localhost:~]$ create-follower test2 user2 otherhost /tmp/log-2.txt
[dsm@localhost:~]$ create-follower test2 user3 remotebox /tmp/log-3.txt
```

Now, activate the followers:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ activate-followers test1 test2 test3
```

To get out of the function use `CTRL+C`, and to stop the backgrounded processes use:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ stop-followers
```

**NOTE 1: This assumes public key authentication has been set up for your boxes.**

**NOTE 2: You will have to kill all the jobs that are left running after quitting the activate-followers function. You may want to do this manually as the function provided does a brute force kill on ALL backgrounded jobs**

**NOTE 3: This assumes a working unix-like environment, which you can get by installing cygwin**

Who says you can't do lisp in shellscript ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout in'side log.

A Java tool I created, able to read local and distant log files using SSH. It is fairly simple to use.

Some more explanations: https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/wiki

Just download the version corresponding to your operating system, or the native jar release executable within your Java Runtime (requires java 8_40 or higher):

https://github.com/pschweitz/insidelog/releases

You can find a complete documentation (embedded with and in Github's page as well)

Comment: Please do read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) before creating posts here; we do appreciate OSS solutions, but make it *relevant to the question* please.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that pop into my mind first.

Choose your favorite SSH app (putty, ssh in cygwin, etc) and log into the machine.
1. SSH for each log (lots of windows open on your machine or tabs depending on your app)
2. SSH once and use [screen](http://aymanh.com/increase-your-linux-unix-productivity-with-gnu-screen).

Comment: thank you.
sounds like it is useful except I am not supposed to install any software on the linux/solaris servers. I need a solution from my windows XP box.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually needed to see both logs at the same time, and tabs were out of the question, you could install a perl script called LogResolveMerge.pl. It'll will merge two logs together, and dump the output to STDOUT. However, it will be resource intensive, and if your intention is to tail -f the logs, it likely won't be too effective.

Comment: thank you for the perl script. I can use it in an alternate scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using fabric, as documented in https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/01/15/fabric-tailing-log-files-on-multiple-machines/ :

> ```
> fab -P --linewise -H host1,host2,host3 -- tail -f /path/to/logfile
> ```